# Как отредактировать страницу приветствия Symfony5? Например вывести в ней phpinfo();

Tags: php, symfony5

Всем привет! Собственно стал вопрос о том как мне вывести phpinfo(); команду после установки Symfony на главной странице сайта?

Простое помещение файла info.php в корень папки с симфони не дает результата его просто не видит - No routes found. По Этому как вариант подскажите как мне поместить phpinfo(); в главную страницу симфони? Или по правильному может как то можно сделать это.

Answer (score 1):

Положите свой info.php в папку public, а не в корень проекта

Comment: Так и делаю вот этой командой потом проверяю файл есть. root:/var/www/html/symfony5/public# echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > info.php
root:/var/www/html/symfony5/public# ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 11 17:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Dec 11 15:19 ../
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 Dec 11 15:57 bundles/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  199 Dec 11 00:58 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   20 Dec 11 17:18 info.php
root:/var/www/html/symfony5/public#
Потом ожидаю увидеть этот файл по адресу /info.php но получаю 404 Not Found

Comment: Спасибо, это верно. Просто у меня какой то трабл с настройкой сервера nginx видимо. Потому что главная симфони при запуске пишет Welcome to Symfony 5.4.1 /var/www/html/symfony5/, а когда я набираю адрес сайта/index.php то 404 Not Found. А ведь index.php лежит в папке public. Не пойму как  он тогда открывается с главной и кудой...

Answer (score 1):

Положите свой info.php в папку public, а не в корень проекта. Содержание файла должно быть таким:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

или сокращенная версия:

```
<?= phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это верно. Просто у меня какой то трабл с настройкой сервера nginx видимо. Потому что главная симфони при запуске пишет Welcome to Symfony 5.4.1 /var/www/html/symfony5/, а когда я набираю адрес сайта/index.php то 404 Not Found. А ведь index.php лежит в папке public. Не пойму как он тогда открывается с главной и кудой...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос удалось решить, проблема заключалась в конфиге на официальном сайте Symfony5 - [см. конфиг](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx)

Там есть во первых Синтаксис:   internal;

Указывает, что location может использоваться только для внутренних запросов. Для внешних запросов клиенту будет возвращаться ошибка 404 (Not Found).
Для внешних и в том числе что я писал что помещаю файл info.php в public и его отрубает - проблема была в этом.

Дополнительно они туда всунули директиву location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {...
которая разрешает открытвать ТОЛЬКО файлы с расширением index.php из домашнего каталога. И ниже приметка что "Это выполняется только index.php в общедоступном каталоге. Все остальные файлы, заканчивающиеся на «.php», будут отклонены."

Вопрос решился убираением из конфига симфони internal; и переписью фразы location ~* .php(/|$) { вместо location ~ ^/index.php(/|$)
Надеюсь кому то поможет кто ставит Symfony 5 по мануалу.